# Serializing a dynamically generated class

Tags: java, serialization, dynamic-class-loaders

Suppose that I have an abstract class

```
public abstract class Base implements Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
    public Base(int x) { ... }
    public abstract void baseMethod();
}
```

and then I dynamically create the class

```
public class Temp {
    public Base getBase() {
        return new Base(2) {

            static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

            @Override
            public void baseMethod() { .... } 
        };
    }
}
```

I am able to generate the class Temp from a String dynamically, invoke a new instance, and extract the base object and use it like any other instance extending Base.  The problem comes when I serialize.  I can serialize the Base base object that I extract from the dynamic Temp class, but then I can't later deserialize in a different session because Temp is no longer on the class path.

Can you guys think of any way around this?  There has to be a way to get the Base object in question in isolation from the Temp class (which I never care about after I've extracted the Base class from it).  The Base object doesn't depend on anything in the Temp class.

Comment: `I am able to generate the class Temp from a String dynamically`. How are you creating the Temp object from `String`?

Comment: What are you using to serialize?

Comment: @VishalK, I am passing a String of the second code block in the OP into some other code that treats it like a .java file and compiles it into a class.  I then invoke the class and get what I need.  This all works fine, I can use the Base object return by getBase() without issue.

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik, just Java's serialization interface.

Comment: You can create a method in Temp class where you deserialize the Base class Object.. in this way you can deserialize the Base class object in any Temp object.

Comment: @VishalK, I don't think you understand what I am doing here (which admittedly is kind of funky). 

1. Generate Temp class dynamically.
2. Get base object and use it in program.
3. Later, potentially serialize base like any other Base object.
4. Maybe reload the serialized base object in a different JVM sessions where Base is on the classloader but Temp is long thrown away.

Comment: You problem could be understood much better if you post other part of your code..while Serializing and deserializing the Base class Object.

Comment: @VishalK, Vishal, my comment may have come off as condescending when I did not intend it to, apologies.  I am hesitant to post more code as the program involves dozens of classes and it is hard to post anything else without context.

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing `writeReplace` on your `Temp` object so that it writes a `Base`, and implement `readResolve` on your `Base` object so that it creates a `Temp` that wraps it.  See the [Serializable contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

The code would look something like this.  Please note that I have not actually tested this, but it should be pretty close.

```
public class Base implements Serializable {
    // Existing members here

    private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
        return new Temp(this);
    }
}

public class Temp implements Serializable {
    Base base;

    public Temp(Base base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    // Other existing methods here

    private Object writeReplace() throws ObjectStreamException {
        return base;
    }
}
```

I realize that this introduces a nasty circular dependency between these two classes, but I don't see another great way of doing this, except for an external reader/writer method as others have suggested.  The advantage of this approach is it supports writing out a `Temp` as part of a larger object graph.

Comment: Hi Eric Galluzzo.  I am having trouble figuring out how to implement what you've suggested (a bit above my paygrade as a humble economist).  I was wondering if it wasn't too much trouble if you could be a bit more specific in what you had in mind,

Answer (score 0):

Well First of all Richard this is really the first time I am seeing this peculiar case thanks for bringing it out ;)
Here I have developed some way out to solve your problem . I hope this might be helpful for you.:

```
import java.io.*;
abstract class Base implements Serializable
{
    protected int x ;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Base(int x) { this.x = x; }
    public abstract void baseMethod();
}
class Temp implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;//Make Temp serializable also.
    public Base getBase(int i) 
    {
        Base base = new Base(i)
        {
            static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public void baseMethod() { System.out.println(x); } 
        };
        return base;
    }
}
public class ReadWriteBaseObject 
{
    public static Base createBaseObject(int i)
    {
        Temp temp = new Temp();//You might be creating your Temp object here Dynamically..
        Base base = temp.getBase(i);
        return base;
    }
    public static Base read()
    {
        ObjectInputStream oin = null;
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("BASE.ser");
            oin = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
            Base base = (Base)oin.readObject();
            return base;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (oin!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    oin.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex){}
            }
        }
    }
    public static void write(Base base)
    {
        if (base == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Can't write null");
            return;
        }
        ObjectOutputStream os = null;
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("BASE.ser");
            os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject(base);
            System.out.println("Wrote to file");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (os!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    os.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex){}
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String st[])
    {
        Base base = createBaseObject(45);
        write(base);
        Base obj = read();
        obj.baseMethod();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Although anonymous class instances, can be serialized successfully but still it is strongly discouraged by Java due to several complication. [**Here**](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4862448) is what the official site of java states:

> Note - **Serialization of inner classes (i.e., nested classes that are
> not   static member classes), including local and anonymous classes,
> is strongly   discouraged for several reasons**. Because inner classes
> declared in non-static   contexts contain implicit non-transient
> references to enclosing class   instances, serializing such an inner
> class instance will result in   serialization of its associated outer
> class instance as well. Synthetic   fields generated by javac (or
> other JavaTM compilers) to implement inner   classes are
> implementation dependent and may vary between compilers;   differences
> in such fields can disrupt compatibility as well as result in
> conflicting default serialVersionUID values. The names assigned to
> local and   anonymous inner classes are also implementation dependent
> and may differ   between compilers. Since inner classes cannot declare
> static members other   than compile-time constant fields, they cannot
> use the serialPersistentFields   mechanism to designate serializable
> fields. Finally, because inner classes   associated with outer
> instances do not have zero-argument constructors   (constructors of
> such inner classes implicitly accept the enclosing instance   as a
> prepended parameter), they cannot implement Externalizable. None of
> the   issues listed above, however, apply to static member classes.

To know more about Serialization in java you can watch [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html)

Comment: Thanks VishalK - Correct me if I am wrong, but wouldn't this require Temp to be on the classpath in later sessions when I try to deserialize?

Comment: @richard can't you use concrete class of Base?

Comment: What do you mean?  For certain reasons Base has to remain and abstract class.

Comment: @richard What i have realized that there is no meaning of serializing an abstract class (until and unless it contains some state) Since they can't be instantiated. What we are doing here is serializing anonymous implementation of Abstract class type defined within the outer class `Temp`. So `base` is like a member of `Temp` class wrapped within `Temp` object. So , We can't deserialize  `Base` without deserialzing `Temp` first.

Comment: @richard: See my update to know about why Serialization of anonymous class instances, is discouraged by Java.